# Example of a function continuous in one variable but not Lebesgue measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f(x, y) : [0, 1] \times [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$. One can show that if $f$ is continuous in $x$ for each fixed $y$ and measurable in $y$ for each fixed $x$, then $f$ itself is Lebesgue measurable.

However, what if $f$ is only continuous in $x$? Then I don't believe $f$ has to be measurable, but I'm having trouble coming up with a counterexample. I was thinking of constructing something containing Cantor's / "devil's staircase" function, but I wonder if there's anything that's simpler to explicitly define.

Comment: The devil's staircase is continuous, so I don't see how it would be helpful in constructing a nonmeasurable function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be any non-measurable function and let 
$f(x,y) = g(y)$.  It is continuous (constant) in $x$, but not measurable.

Comment: Do you have an example of a non-measurable function g?

Comment: @CFish the characteristic function of any non-measurable set will do.

Comment: To add to @James, you're not going to get any explicit examples of a non-measurable set.  Any example I know of uses the axiom of choice in some way (and I believe there is good reason for this).  Nonetheless a relatively simple example is described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-measurable_set.